# when function name end with `!`

Tags: elixir

Consider [`Application.fetch_env!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.4/Application.html#content).
What’s the special meaning for ending with `!` for a function name?

```elixir
defp db_host do
  Application.fetch_env!(:my_app, :db_host)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the **Naming Convention** section "Trailing Bang": https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.4/naming-conventions.html#trailing-bang-foo

> A trailing bang (exclamation mark) signifies a function or macro where failure cases raise an exception.

So the function `Application.fetch_env!` will raise an `ArgumentError` when the configuration parameter does not exist (as stated in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.4/Application.html#fetch_env!/2)) while `Application.fetch_env` (without exclamation mark) will return an `:error` in case of a non-existing parameter